# pdp plotPartial unable to change zlim

Tags: r, plot, pdp

I am plotting some partial dependences plots in R, for random forest. I am using pdp package and it is not reacting to any specification for my limits in z variable.
code:

```
pd <- partial(RF, pred.var= c ( "SOC", "Q"))
plotPartial(pd, zlim=c(1000,3000))
```

i had also tried:
zlim(c(1000,3000), and zmax and min and similars

Comment: You should try to post a complete example that reproduces your problem. It will be hard to help you with the question as-is, because people don't have the contents of the `RF` object

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion, here is my code

```
library(randomForest) #fitting RF
library(pdp) #partial dependence analysis
```

```
set.seed(100)
RF=randomForest(CorrYield~Year+SOC+pH+ Sorghum+Pbray + FertP+ FertN+ PP_veg +PP_PC, data= RF_sin1 , ntree=500, importance=T, proximity=T)
```

```
pd_SOC_P <- partial(RF, pred.var= c("SOC", "Pbray"))
plotPartial(pd_SOC_P,xlab="SOC(%)", ylab="PBray(mg kg^-1)")
```